# Difference between Newtonsoft Json DynamicValueProvider and ReflectionValueProvider?

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm in the process of porting a Asp.Net Core Website targeting the full framework to a website that targets Asp.Net Core 3.

In that process I have hit a snag.  The website references the Newtonsoft 11.0.3 NuGet package and among other things uses the `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider` class.

Interestingly that class exists when targeting the full framework but does not exist when targeting `netcoreapp3.1` and so Visual Studio is producing compilation errors stating that the class doesn't exist.  At first that seemed crazy to me, but I checked the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/11.0.2/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DynamicValueProvider.cs) for the class and sure enough it contains the following conditional compilation statement wrapped around the whole class

> #if HAVE_REFLECTION_EMIT

Apparently the netStandard 2.0 dll in the NuGet package that my `netcoreapp3.1` project would use causes the conditional compilation statement to not include the `DynamicValueProvider` class.

So I did some poking around in the `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization` namespace and I see that there is a `ReflectionValueProvider` class available that does not contain such conditional compilation and is available when targeting `netcoreapp3.1`

I've looked at the source code for both the `DynamicValueProvider` class and the  `ReflectionValueProvider` class and I'm unclear on the difference.  Both appear to get or set the value of a property or member type based on the `MemberInfo` passed in into the constructor.  Both appear to use reflection to accomplish their work.  As I mentioned, apparently `DynamicValueProvider` needs reflection Emit ability and `ReflectionValueProvider` does not. Emit ability apparently is used to Emit IL as best I can tell.

So I wonder if perhaps the two are drop in replacements for each other except that maybe DynamicValueProvider might be faster since it apparently leverages IL Emitting.  But that's just a hunch.  I'd prefer to have a more concrete understanding of the differences between the two classes before I start swapping the one for the other in this existing codebase as a way to get to .Net Core 3.

Can you provide me with better insight into the differences between the `DynamicValueProvider` 
class and the `ReflectionValueProvider`  class, or at least confirm my hunch?

Answer (score 2):

We had updated Newtonsoft.Json from 9.* to 12.0.3 version, and observed performance degradation on paths that includes json serialization. All paths lead to DynamicValueProvider. Fortunately, we had global descendant for DefaultContractResolver, and I was able to overload CreateMemberValueProvider method to return ReflectionValueProvider.

For now we are continue testing the new version, but I can say that from performance perspective ReflectionValueProvider works faster than DynamicValueProvider.

Comment: That you are observing `ReflectionValueProvider`  to be faster than `DynamicValueProvider` is truly puzzling give that both appear to use reflection but `DynamicValueProvider` also  leverages IL Emitting.  This makes me even more curious as to why the two classes exist instead of just one of them.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that we target .net 4.5.2, and run on 4.6.1. Maybe DynamicValueProvider has better performance for netcore.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a correlation with the fact that NetStandard 2.0 is also used to build Xamarin.Forms applications for iOS which require an AOT compilation.

As written here:
[Limitations of Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations)

"Since applications using Xamarin.iOS are compiled to static code, it is not possible to use any facilities that require code generation at runtime."

and

"No Dynamic Code Generation.
The System.Reflection.Emit is not available"

For example, this is a System.Text.Json limitation that actually cannot be used in Xamarin.Forms projects for iOS. More info here.

[System.Text.Json Serializer does not appear to work on Xamarin iOS](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31326#issue-558483738)

Comment: That is interesting for sure and seems to give a nod to my hunch.